# How To Adding Timestamp when Webstream Video Raspberry-Pi Python?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I want webstreaming video using Raspberry-pi. I used Raspberry-pi Camera. I want to adding timestamp and other text in my webstreaming video. But my webstream just show first iteration text. For example, i run my raspberry-pi 07-01-22 14:14 when 15:00 i refresh webstream and the text show "07-01-22 14:14" again. what should i do?

My Python Code:

````
# Source code from the official PiCamera package
# http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming

import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server
import datetime

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>Camera Security Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Camera Security Report</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480"></center>
</body>
</html>
"""

def show_time():
    ''' Show current date time in text format '''
    rightNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    currentTime = ("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % (rightNow.year,
                                                      rightNow.month,
                                                      rightNow.day,
                                                      rightNow.hour,
                                                      rightNow.minute,
                                                      rightNow.second))
    return currentTime

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=60) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    #Uncomment the next line to change your Pi's Camera rotation (in degrees)
    #camera.rotation = 90
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    camera.annotate_text = show_time()
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever() 
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Define the annotate_text before start_recording().

Comment: where `start_recording()` ??

Comment: You have a start_recording(...) call in your code already. Put a call: camera.wait_recording(0.2)
 in the loop, it will update the annotation text (I think).

Comment: oke, i will try it. If that solution solves this problem. I will tell you.